# Yup validation based on nested object within nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I currently have an object that looks like the following:

```
const initialValues = {
  created: {
    position: 1,
    name: 'created',
    type: 'timestamp',
    desc: 'The date and time the lead is created',
    mapping: {
      name: '',
      defaultValue: '',
      map: false
    }
  }
}
```

I would like the name within the mapping object to become required when the map value within the map object is set to a value of true.  I have attempted this by doing the following:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  created: yup.object().when('mapping.map', {
    is: true,
    then: yup.object({
      mapping: yup.object({
        name: yup.string().required('name is required')
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I believe I'm not tunneling enough in order to accurately set up the validation for the mapping object, any and all help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution doing the following:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  created: yup.object().shape({
    mapping: yup.object().shape({
      map: yup.boolean(),
      defaultValue: yup.string(),
      name: yup.string().when('map', {
        is: true,
        then: yup.string().required('name is required')
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks - you saved me a lot of headache 